# Progressive Web Apps and Private SQL Credentials

Tags: javascript, sql, progressive-web-apps

I am tasked with converting a PHP application into a progressive web app. This entails converting the existing PHP logic into JavaScript that runs client-side.

However, the PHP application contains sensitive information, including SQL credentials, which must never be leaked. This complicates the conversion because one of the biggest requirements of a progressive web app is Offline First, or the ability to operate without an Internet connection and/or not slow down even if an Internet connection is available.

Encrypting the JavaScript code is not an option because, no matter how strong the encryption, the decryption code must be shipped alongside it, and thus, determined hackers will always be able to crack the encryption. HTTPS cannot prevent hackers from jailbreaking their phones.

On the other hand, sending an Ajax request to a proxy server that holds the sensitive credentials will slow down the application, defeating the whole point of progressive web applications.

I have spent hours looking up solutions online, yet nothing I found is relevant enough. So how should developers go about ensuring that SQL credentials and other sensitive information are never exposed in the progressive web app?

**EDIT:** I should clarify that, while I understand that synchronizing local data with server data is the preferred behavior of progressive web apps, I am explicitly forbidden from doing so in this particular case. The data must be kept confidential.

Comment: Your SQL credentials shouldn't be anywhere *near* client-side code.  PWA doesn't mean "no server side code"

Comment: Missing the point of how PWA works. When online you synchronize local data with server data.

Comment: @charlietfl: You have a point, and I wish I could follow your advice, but in my case, I'm expressly forbidden from having clients download any data for confidentiality reasons. I should edit the question to clarify this fact...

Comment: Data is always downloaded to the client, how long you choose to retain it is another matter.  Obviously you can't be "offline first" and "no offline" - someone has to make up their mind one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question on how to store your DB passwords safely in client side, **"you can't"**. Anything at client side is not for sensitive information like server side DB password.

**PWA is a web application end of the day** with new features. But those doesn't gives you any added security to perform server side like operations which you can hide from users. Even if you use HTTPS, it will only encrypt data over network.

**What if you use:** If you store "DB password" in a PWA app or any web app for that matter, user can get the password using Chrome Dev tools for example and use that to connect to DB directly to get all the data in it, not just his.

**Solution:** PHP is a server side scripting language. When you convert that to HTML/JS, server side code from it will be remaining for your to put it again in server side itself and expose the data using web services to PWA.

**On Downloading data:** Caching is not plainly equivalent to downloading. [Read more on here](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker) and if you still don't want caching, you "Network only" mode as explained in the same link and make use of other PWA aspects..like notifications, install to home screen.